# Is this sufficient to show that the partial sums converge?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, convergence-divergence

I am trying to show explicitly that the partial sums (for the series $\sum \frac{1}{j(j+1)}$ from j=1 to $\infty$) converge. Would it be sufficient to say that by looking at $\sum \frac{1}{j(j+1)}$ = $\frac{1}{j}-\frac{1}{j+1}$ and $\frac{1}{j}-\frac{1}{j+1} \rightarrow 0$ as $j \rightarrow \infty$?

There is a theorem in the book that says that if $\sum a_j$ converges, then $a_j \rightarrow 0$ as $j \rightarrow \infty$, but I dont know if this is an iff condition that holds the other way.

Comment: It is not an if and only if statement. Look at the sequence $1/n$ for a counterexample.

Comment: Since the harmonic series is a counterexample, would the way to show this explicitly be by selecting an epsilon>0 and and n,m>N and showing that the absolute value of the sequence would be less than a given epsilon for all n,m>N?

Comment: It is a little bit confusing when you write $\sum\frac1{j(j+1)}=\frac1j-\frac1{j+1}$ without bounds of summation.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**. Here the partial sum is easy to handle, you have ([a telescoping sum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TelescopingSum.html))
$$
\sum_{j=1}^N \frac{1}{j(j+1)}=\sum_{j=1}^N \left(\frac{1}j-\frac{1}{j+1}\right)=1-\frac{1}{N+1},\qquad N\geq1.
$$
[This](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~park/Fall2011/sequences/telescoping.pdf) may interest you.

Answer (score 1):

You can prove convergence via a comparison test. We have,

$\sum_{j =1}^{j =\infty} \frac{1}{(j+1)j} = \sum_{j =1}^{j =\infty} \frac{1}{j^2 +j}  \leq \sum_{j =1}^{j =\infty} \frac{1}{j^2}$

Now it is known that $\sum_{j =1}^{j =\infty} \frac{1}{j^2}$ converges, and thus

$\sum_{j =1}^{j =\infty} \frac{1}{(j+1)j}$ converges.

Answer (score 0):

About the theorem, no it is not an **if and only if**! This theorem is widely used to prove divergence of series from its **logical equivalence** that states:

> **Logical Equivalence of the Theorem**. If $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } {a_n} \ne 0$  then $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \sum\limits_{i = p}^n {{a_n}}$ does not exist or diverges.

About the convergence, as your partial sum is a **telescoping** one you can simply derive a formula for the partial sum and then evaluate the limit of the partial sum (convergence of series)

$$\sum\limits_{j = p}^n {{1 \over {j(j + 1)}}}  = \sum\limits_{j = p}^n {{1 \over j} - } {1 \over {j + 1}} = {1 \over p} - {1 \over {n + 1}}$$

and hence

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \sum\limits_{i = p}^n {{a_n}}  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } {1 \over p} - {1 \over {n + 1}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } {1 \over p} - \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } {1 \over {n + 1}} = {1 \over p} - 0 = {1 \over p}$$

Comment: @byong: Take a look at this. Hope this helps! :)